# js dice 6 images and stopping one by one

Tags: javascript, html

Im currently making a site that will have 6 different images with the image name mydice1, mydice2, mydice3 , mydice4, mydice5 and mydice6.

also in my assets/bilder/sekserspillet folder i have dices image with the name die-NumberOfDice.gif
How can i edit this function to do the following:

when starting all of the 6 images are diceing ( changing from 1-6), one after one, starting with mydice1 they will stop rolling ( aka stop changing images, and get back to the original image), then a few secs later, the image with dice mydice2 will do the same, etc.

so in short:
all dices are changing images when running, and then one by one, they will stop rolling and get back to the original image.

```
        function throwdices() {
    var spins = spins;
    var curSpin = 0;
    var spinInterval = setInterval(function() {
        curSpin++;
        if (curSpin < spins) {
            var randomdices=Math.round(Math.random()*4.5);
            document.images["mydice1"].src="assets/bilder/sekserspillet/die-"+randomdices+".gif";
        } else {
            clearInterval(spinInterval);
            throwdice();
        }
    }, 500);
}
```

my html:

```
    <img src="assets/bilder/sekserspillet/die-<?echo $terninger[0]?>.gif" width="45px" height="45px" name="mydice1">
<img src="assets/bilder/sekserspillet/die-<?echo $terninger[1]?>.gif" width="45px" height="45px" name="mydice2">
<img src="assets/bilder/sekserspillet/die-<?echo $terninger[2]?>.gif" width="45px" height="45px" name="mydice3">
<img src="assets/bilder/sekserspillet/die-<?echo $terninger[3]?>.gif" width="45px" height="45px" name="mydice4">
<img src="assets/bilder/sekserspillet/die-<?echo $terninger[4]?>.gif" width="45px" height="45px" name="mydice5">
<img src="assets/bilder/sekserspillet/die-<?echo $terninger[5]?>.gif" width="45px" height="45px" name="mydice6">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some years ago i had answered [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4306465/128165).

Here is an adaptation for your needs: http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/zZUgF/262/

The difference is that i am using `div` elements instead of images, and the image is a sprite (*with all states inside it*) so that all states of the dice are loaded at once.

```js
$('#throw').click(function () {
    $('.dice').each(function(index){
        throwAnimatedDice( this, index );
    });
    
});

function throwAnimatedDice(elem, spins) {
    var value = Math.round(Math.random() * 5) + 1;
    displayDice(10 + (spins*5), value, $(elem));

    return value;
}

function displayDice(times, final, element) {
    element.removeClass();
    if (times > 1) {
        element.addClass('dice dice_' + (Math.round(Math.random() * 5) + 1));
        setTimeout(function () {
            displayDice(times - 1, final, element);
        }, 100);
    } else element.addClass('dice dice_' + final);
}
```

```css
.dice {
    background-image:url('http://www.clker.com/cliparts/e/7/4/4/1194991183406177705six-sided_dice_faces_lio_01.svg.med.png');
    height:49px;
    width:49px;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:5px;
}
.dice_1 {
    background-position:0px 0px;
}
.dice_2 {
    background-position:-50px 0px;
}
.dice_3 {
    background-position:-101px 0px;
}
.dice_4 {
    background-position:-151px 0px;
}
.dice_5 {
    background-position:-201px 0px;
}
.dice_6 {
    background-position:-251px 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dice dice_6"></div>
<div class="dice dice_6"></div>
<div class="dice dice_6"></div>
<div class="dice dice_6"></div>
<div class="dice dice_6"></div>
<div class="dice dice_6"></div>
<br />
<br />
<button id="throw">throw dice</button>
```